# PHP arrays be outputed to JSON format

Tags: php, json

PHP arrays

```
$grades = array( array( name => "tom", 
                  grade => 'A'

                ),
           array( name => "jeff", 
                  grade=> 'B'

                ),
           array( name => "lisa", 
                  grade => 'C'
                )
         );

$output=array
(  'status'=>'ok',
   'content'=>$grades
)
```

And the final JSON output I want to see would be `{"status":'ok',"content":"{"tom":"A","jeff":"B","lisa":"B"}"}`

***The question is how should I manipulated the array so it can give me the final output like above JSON?***
would `json_encode($output); echo $output` do the trick?
or
Do I have to do

`json_encode($grades)`   then another `json_encodes($output)` but I am seeing extra `\` thing like `{"status":1,"content":"{\"tom\":\"A\",\"jeff\":\"B\",\"lisa\":\"B\"}"}`

Comment: Why don't you try and see what happens?

Comment: I try but couldn't get that final result I wanted to see.

Comment: Do you really want to content to be a quoted object literal?  Maybe you actually want it to be an object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why you don't write just this:

```
<?php
$grades = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'tom',
        'grade' => 'A'
    ),

    array(
        'name' => 'jeff',
        'grade' => 'B'
    ),

    array(
        'name' => 'lisa',
        'grade' => 'C'
    ),
);

$output = array(
    'status'  => 'ok',
    'content' => $grades,
);

print_r(json_decode(json_encode($output)));
```

It prints:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [status] => ok
    [content] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => tom
                    [grade] => A
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => jeff
                    [grade] => B
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => lisa
                    [grade] => C
                )

        )

)
```

Isn't is the expected result?

Answer (score 9):

Try this simple command

```
$my_array = [
    "test" => "value", 
    "another" => [
        "fruits" => ["Apple", "Orange"]
    ]
];

print_r(json_encode($my_array));
```

It will produce

```
{
    "test":"value",
    "another":{
        "fruits":["Apple","Orange"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't call `json_encode($grades)` before `json_encode($output)`, unless you have some unmentioned reason to want the grades as a string literal instead of json object. `json_encode()` will recursively encode all child arrays inside `$output`, there's no need to encode them separately.

Answer (score 1):

As you may have figured out, an array's associative keys get represented as keys in the resulting JSON object, e.g. **{key1: value1, ...}**, as clearly demonstrated from the output you got.
Secondly, an array containing other arrays will be represented as a list in JSON, e.g. **[...]**
I believe your earlier code should looked something like this:

```
$grades = array(
    array('name' => 'tom', 'grade' => 'A'),
    array('name' => 'jeff', 'grade' => 'B'),
    array('name' => 'lise', 'grade' => 'C'),
);

$output = array(
    'status' => 'ok',
    'content' => $grades
);

echo json_encode($output);
```

So applying the rules I have outlined above will result in the JSON below.

```
{"status":"ok","content":[{"name":"tom","grade":"A"},{"name":"jeff","grade":"B"},{"name":"lise","grade":"C"}]}
```

I personally think you should use this since it is a better representation than the one you desire to have. However, the codes below should give you your results.

```
$grades = array(
    'tom' => 'A',
    'jeff' => 'B',
    'lisa' => 'B',
);

$output = array(
    'status' => 'ok',
    'content' => $grades
);

echo json_encode($output);
```

Output:

```
{"status":"ok","content":{"tom":"A","jeff":"B","lisa":"B"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the 'extra' \ is that what you say you want as output is not valid JSON. PHP's default function has it right, yours will not parse in a JSON parser.

If you really want almost-json, you'll have to roll your own.

Comment: You mean there are no standard way to see  {"status":'ok',"content":"{"tom":"A","jeff":"B","lisa":"B"}"}  ?

Comment: No.  Quotes must be escaped inside of quotes in JavaScript.  What you want is a syntax error.

Comment: @lilzz no, there is a standard way - the way that PHP encoded it. I saying that the way you want to have encoded it is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the format of `$grade` array to get the desired output . try below

```
$grade_format= array();
foreach($grades as $k=>$v)
{
 //array_push($output,$k);
 $grade_format[$v['name']]=$v['grade'];
}
//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($grade_format);

$output=array
(  'status'=>'ok',
   'content'=>$grade_format
);

echo "<pre>";
echo json_encode($output,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
//output would be 
{"status":"ok","content":{"tom":"A","jeff":"B","lisa":"C"}}
```

is that you want??

[`REFERENCE`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)